# How do I access both levels of associative arrays which both use varchar2 for index with PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, nested, associative-array

I'm trying to access the second level of a nest associative array indexed only by varchar2 and I'm running into a problem.  Every example I've found on the net uses an integer as an index somewhere and that's not helping me.

Here's some example code:

```
DECLARE

    l_idx1 VARCHAR(50);
    l_idx2 VARCHAR(50);

    TYPE counter_type IS RECORD (
        updated INTEGER,
        inserted INTEGER,
        deleted INTEGER
    );

    TYPE counter_tab IS TABLE OF counter_type INDEX BY VARCHAR2(50);

    counters counter_tab;

BEGIN

    counters('example_table1').updated := 0;
    counters('example_table1').inserted := 0;
    counters('example_table1').deleted := 0;

    counters('example_table2').updated := 0;
    counters('example_table2').inserted := 0;
    counters('example_table2').deleted := 0;

    counters('example_table3').updated := 0;
    counters('example_table3').inserted := 0;
    counters('example_table3').deleted := 0;

    counters('example_table3').inserted := counters('example_table3').inserted + 12;
    counters('example_table2').updated := counters('example_table2').updated + 32;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('foo: ' || counters('example_table2').updated); -- testing this out


    l_idx1 := counters.FIRST;
    WHILE l_idx1 IS NOT NULL
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('idx: ' || l_idx1);
        l_idx2 := counters(l_idx1).FIRST;  - This is where the problem is!!
        WHILE l_idx2 IS NOT NULL
        LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Table: ' || l_idx1 || 'Counter: ' || counters(l_idx1).l_idx2);
            IF counters(l_idx1).l_idx2 > 0
            THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Records ' || l_idx2 || ' for table ' || l_idx1 || ': ' || counters(l_idx1).l_idx2); 
            END IF;

            l_idx2 := counters(l_ldx1).NEXT(l_idx2);  --  Like another problem!
        END LOOP;
        l_idx1 := counters.NEXT(l_idx1);
    END LOOP;

END;
/
```

So, what I'm trying to do is loop through the first level associative array and for each one of those loop through the second level array and print out the values.  Seems like it would be pretty simple and it probably is.  :-)

Thanks for any assistance!!

lkl

Comment: You have an array of record: this is not a nested array.

Answer (score 0):

You have just one level of the array(`counter_tab`) of type `counter_type`.

You can loop through the `counters` but there is no array inside counters so that is not possible.

Use the following code in case it helps:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2  L_IDX1     VARCHAR(50);
  3  L_IDX2     VARCHAR(50);
  4  TYPE COUNTER_TYPE IS RECORD (
  5  UPDATED    INTEGER,
  6  INSERTED   INTEGER,
  7  DELETED    INTEGER
  8  );
  9  TYPE COUNTER_TAB IS
 10  TABLE OF COUNTER_TYPE INDEX BY VARCHAR2(50);
 11  COUNTERS   COUNTER_TAB;
 12  BEGIN
 13  COUNTERS('example_table1').UPDATED    := 0;
 14  COUNTERS('example_table1').INSERTED   := 0;
 15  COUNTERS('example_table1').DELETED    := 0;
 16  COUNTERS('example_table2').UPDATED    := 0;
 17  COUNTERS('example_table2').INSERTED   := 0;
 18  COUNTERS('example_table2').DELETED    := 0;
 19  COUNTERS('example_table3').UPDATED    := 0;
 20  COUNTERS('example_table3').INSERTED   := 0;
 21  COUNTERS('example_table3').DELETED    := 0;
 22  COUNTERS('example_table3').INSERTED   := COUNTERS('example_table3').INSERTED + 12;
 23  COUNTERS('example_table2').UPDATED    := COUNTERS('example_table2').UPDATED + 32;
 24  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('foo: ' || COUNTERS('example_table2').UPDATED); -- testing this out
 25  L_IDX1                                := COUNTERS.FIRST;
 26  WHILE L_IDX1 IS NOT NULL LOOP
 27  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('idx: ' || L_IDX1);
 28  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('updated: ' || COUNTERS(L_IDX1).UPDATED);
 29  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('inserted: ' || COUNTERS(L_IDX1).INSERTED);
 30  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('deleted: ' || COUNTERS(L_IDX1).DELETED);
 31  L_IDX1 := COUNTERS.NEXT(L_IDX1);
 32  END LOOP;
 33
 34  END;
 35  /
foo: 32
idx: example_table1
updated: 0
inserted: 0
deleted: 0
idx: example_table2
updated: 32
inserted: 0
deleted: 0
idx: example_table3
updated: 0
inserted: 12
deleted: 0

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but that's not really what I'm after.  I don't want to have to know what the indexes are of the second level array.  I want to be able to add as many as I'd like and not hard code those into the DBMS_OUTPUT.

Comment: It is not hardcoded. You can add as many `counter_tab` as you want into `counters`

Comment: By hard coded I mean that it's hard coded in this line:

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('updated: ' || COUNTERS(L_IDX1).UPDATED);

What I'm looking to do is something like this:  COUNTERS(L_IDX1).L_IDX2

Comment: Not possible. You must use the name of the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you are looking for; it is just how you go about it is drastically different. 
First off lets clear up your misconception of what needs an index (subscript) and how you reference a Record. When you 
define a type Record you do not access it by a index, (as others have indicated) you can **only access record attributes by name**. 
In this manner a record is referenced the same as a table. When referencing a table column you use syntax TABLE_NAME.COLUMN_NAME likewise a record attribute is referenced as RECORD_NAME.ATTRIBUTE_NAME.  
The only plsql object referenced by an index is a collection (nested table, associative array, varray). So to get what you want you need to declare a **collection of a collection** not a collection of a record. In this case an associative array of an associative array of integers. Further the manner of indexing, each index is enclosed in parentheses separate from the other(s) so C(i1)(i2) instead of C(i1,i2). You also have to keep in mind what level you want to reference as the collection properties (first, last, next, ...) and such are indexed independently (sort of). But if you can keep it all straight, there is no limit to the number of levels (AFAIK).  
The following shows how to go about what you want. Is it worth the effort? In this case probably not unless your full issue needs references without prior knowledge of index value (in which case you need to guard against NO_DATA_FOUND exception) or you need to add index values on the fly. Only you can decide that.

```
declare
  l_idx1     varchar(50);       -- 1st level index
  l_idx2     varchar(8);        -- 2nd level index

  -- 2nd level collection. Defines a collection of integers
  type counter_type is  
       table of integer
       index by varchar2(8) ;           

  -- 1st level collection.  Defines a collection of a collection of integers
  type counter_tab is
       table of counter_type 
       index by varchar2(50);

  -- variable for collection of a collection of integers
  counters   counter_tab;

begin
  -- initialize counters
  counters('example_table1')('updated')    := 0;
  counters('example_table1')('inserted')   := 0;
  counters('example_table1')('deleted')    := 0;

  counters('example_table2')('updated')    := 0;
  counters('example_table2')('inserted')   := 0;
  counters('example_table2')('deleted')    := 0;

  counters('example_table3')('updated')    := 0;
  counters('example_table3')('inserted')   := 0;
  counters('example_table3')('deleted')    := 0;

  -- perform some operations  
  counters('example_table3')('inserted')   := counters('example_table3')('inserted') + 12;
  counters('example_table2')('updated')    := counters('example_table2')('updated') + 32;

  -- loop through results 
  l_idx1 := counters.first;
  while l_idx1 is not null 
  loop
      dbms_output.put_line('Outer index: ' || l_idx1);
      l_idx2 := counters(l_idx1).first ; 
      while l_idx2 is not null 
      loop 
          dbms_output.put_line('   ''' || l_idx2 || ':'' '  || to_char(counters(l_idx1)(l_idx2)));
          l_idx2 := counters(l_idx1).next(l_idx2);
     end loop; 
  l_idx1 := counters.next(l_idx1);
  end loop;

end;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  That was exactly what I was looking for!!

Comment: If the answer resolved your issue please accept it. If not what are the remaining issues. Please do not the question unresolved.